# Does gpiozero need RPi.GPIO?

Tags: python-3, raspbian-buster, gpiozero

I'm trying out `gpiozero`, but after running the examples from their documentation, I still get this errors but it still runs ok.

gpiozero is installed on venv using pip3

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause

def say_hello():
    print("Hello!")

button = Button(2)

button.when_pressed = say_hello

pause()
```

```
/home/pi/gpiozero/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py:279: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from rpigpio: No module named 'RPi'                         
  'Falling back from %s: %s' % (name, str(e))))

/home/pi/gpiozero/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py:279: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from rpio: No module named 'RPIO'                           
  'Falling back from %s: %s' % (name, str(e))))

/home/pi/gpiozero/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py:279: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from pigpio: No module named 'pigpio'                       
  'Falling back from %s: %s' % (name, str(e))))
```

If I install `RPi.GPIO` the error goes away.

Comment: The real question is **WHY** you felt the need to install gpiozero - it is included in Raspbian. You have probably nobbled it by installing a private copy.

Comment: GPIOZero is a superset of RPi.GPIO.

Comment: @Milliways it is not included in Raspbian Lite. I am using venv for my project

Comment: In which case you should install, following the Foundation instructions `sudo apt install python3-gpiozero` NOT install a private copy

Comment: @Milliways Your "sudo apt install python3-gpiozero" needs to be an answer, not a comment. It is the correct solution for people (like me) who installed raspian-lite and reach for pip when python packages are needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**gpiozero** does not need `RPi.GPIO`.  However there is little reason not to install `RPi.GPIO`, it doesn't take much space and there are a wealth of examples of its usage.

**gpiozero** can use any one of a number of GPIO library backends to carry out its tasks.

By default it uses `RPi.GPIO`.

If `RPi.GPIO` is not installed it defaults to `RPIO.GPIO`.

If `RPIO.GPIO` is not installed it defaults to `pigpio`.

You don't have to exclusively use the default.  You can tell **gpiozero** to use any of the above GPIO libraries (if it's installed) for a specific function.

Answer (score 1):

***Question***

> Do I need to install Rpi.GIPIO for GPIO Zero?

***Answer***

> Well, GPIO Zero builds on Rpi.GPIO and other libraries.  So if your
>   raspbian does not have it preinstalled, you need to do so.

***References***

(1) [Gpiozero 1.5.1 Documentation > Docs » gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

*Pin factories*

... 
***GPIO Zero builds on*** a number of underlying pin libraries, including ***RPi.GPIO*** and pigpio, each with their own benefits. You can select a particular pin library to be used, either for the whole script or per-device, according to your needs. See the section on changing the pin factory.